# Ext4 on magnetic disk: Is it possible to process an arbitrary list of files in a seek-optimized manner?

Tags: linux, performance, io, filesystems, ext4

I have a deduplicated storage of some million files in a two-level hashed directory structure. The filesystem is an ext4 partition on a magnetic disk. The path of a file is computed by its MD5 hash like this:

```
e93ac67def11bbef905a7519efbe3aa7 -> e9/3a/e93ac67def11bbef905a7519efbe3aa7
```

When processing* a list of files sequentially (selected by metadata stored in a separate database), I can literally hear the noise produced by the seeks ("randomized" by the hashed directory layout as I assume).

**My actual question is:** *Is there a (generic) way to process a potentially long list of potentially small files in a seek-optimized manner, given they are stored on an ext4 partition on a magnetic disk (implying the use of linux)?*

Such optimization is of course only useful if there is a sufficient share of small files. So please don't care too much about the size distribution of files. Without loss of generality, you may actually assume that there are only small files in each list.

As a potential solution, I was thinking of sorting the files by their physical disk locations or by other (heuristic) criteria that can be related to the total amount and length of the seek operations needed to process the entire list.

**A note on file types and use cases for illustration (if need be)**

The files are a deduplicated backup of several desktop machines. So any file you would typically find on a personal computer will be included on the partition. The processing however will affect **only a subset of interest that is selected via the database**.

Here are some use cases for illustration (list is not exhaustive):

- extract metadata from media files (ID3, EXIF etc.) (files may be large, but only some small parts of the files are read, so they become effectively smaller)
- compute smaller versions of all JPEG images to process them with a classifier
- reading portions of the storage for compression and/or encryption (e.g. put all files newer than X and smaller than Y in a tar archive)
- extract the headlines of all Word documents
- recompute all MD5 hashes to verify data integrity

---

While researching for this question, I learned of the `FIBMAP` `ioctl` command (e.g. mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106857/how-can-i-find-out-a-files-range-of-lbas-using-its-inode)) which may be worth a shot, because the files will not be moved around and the results may be stored along the metadata. But I suppose that will only work as sort criterion if the location of a file's inode correlates somewhat with the location of the contents. **Is that true for ext4?**

---

*) i.e. opening each file and reading the head of the file (arbitrary number of bytes) or the entire file into memory.

Comment: First, you have to define what you mean by "process the files".

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sorry to have been unclear. Please see my edit.

Comment: What kind of files are these? What typical size and content? Why do you use millions of files (instead of some database)? What kind of application do you have in mind? Please **edit your question** to improve it with more motivation and context.

Comment: Don't comment your own question, but please edit it. Also explain your application...

Comment: Even with the edits, the use cases are not clear enough... And what are your mount options (e.g. in `/etc/fstab`) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I appreciate your feedback but I respectfully disagree. I asked the question on the exact level of abstraction that I would like to have it answered. The use case is quite plain: Opening and reading a potentially long list of potentially small files in a seek-optimized manner, given the constraints ext4, linux and magnetic. If there is no answer in that generality, that is OK for me. The additional details I provided were mostly meant for illustration instead of specification. You are free to flag or downvote this question if you think it is low-quality (or leave it be).

Comment: Your question could be good (however, what really matters is the distribution of file size). But it has no real answer, because you are confusing various levels of abstractions.

Comment: I streamlined the question after all the edits. I did not see the confusion of layers of abstractions, however. As for the size distribution, please see the final edit.

Answer (score 1):

A file (especially when it is large enough) is scattered on several blocks on the disk (look e.g. in the figure of [ext2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) wikipage, it still is somehow relevant for [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4), even if details are different). More importantly, it could be in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) (so won't require any disk access). So "sorting the file list by disk location" usually does not make any sense.

I recommend instead improving the code accessing these files. Look into system calls like [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) and [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html).

If the files are really small (hundreds of bytes each only), it is probable that using something else (e.g. [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or some real RDBMS like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/), or [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) ...) could be faster.

BTW, adding more RAM could enlarge the page cache size, so the overall experience. And replacing your HDD by some SSD would also help.

(see also [linuxatemyram](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/))

> Is it possible to sort a list of files to optimize read speed / minimize seek times?

That is not really possible. File system fragmentation is not (in practice) important with ext4. Of course, backing up all your file system (e.g. in some tar or cpio archive) and restoring it sequentially (after making a fresh file system with `mkfs`)  might slightly lower fragmentation, but not that much.

You might optimize your file system settings (block size, cluster size, etc... e.g. various arguments to [mke2fs(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mke2fs.8.html)). See also [ext4(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html).

> Is there a (generic) way to process a potentially long list of potentially small files in a seek-optimized manner.

If the list is not too long (otherwise, split it in chunks of several hundred files each), you might [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) each file there and use [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) on each such file descriptor (and then [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) it). This would somehow prefill your [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) (and the kernel *could* reorder the required IO operations).

<sup>(I don't know how effective is that in your case; you need to benchmark)</sup>

I am not sure there is a software solution to your issue. Your problem is likely IO-bound, so the bottleneck is probably the hardware.

Notice that on most current hard disks, the [CHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector) addressing (used by the kernel) is some "logical" addressing handled by the disk controller and is not much related to physical geometry any more. Read about [LBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing), [TCQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Command_Queuing), [NCQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing) (so today, the kernel has no *direct* influence on the actual mechanical movements of a hard disk head). [I/O scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_scheduling) mostly happens in the hard disk itself (not much more in the kernel).

Comment: I will look into the syscalls. I was aware of caches and fragmentation but I did not want to complicate the question because I want *some* improvement and not necessarily an exhaustive optimization.

Comment: Could you also please edit your question to explain what are these files and what is your application?